# Simultaneously including two shocks to the same response variable

Tags: impulse-response

I am trying to generate the impulse response from local projection. My shock variables are interest rate and exchange rate. The response variable is Stock market returns. How can I generate an IRF where I can represent two shocks in the same figure? Precisely my figure should look like two impulse responses with confidence bands with the same shock variable